# Can you buy ranks with Visa gift cards on store.Hypixel.net?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am a avid Hypixel fan, but recently I have been stuck waiting in queue's to get in the main Hypixel lobbies. When I'm in a queue, it says that you can skip the queue by getting a rank. I really want to get a rank, but I don't want to give my credit card info to the Hypixel store. Would I be able to use a Visa gift card like [this](https://www.possupply.com/mastercardr-visar-credit-card-decals-4-decals-package?gclid=CjwKCAjwkqPrBRA3EiwAKdtwk5Esaj-qNkp3rF5ToWSmr5WuR7Vlk3poMdBuisgYLYHQKx6Kfy1yqRoCLLMQAvD_BwE) to buy myself a rank?

Comment: Could anybody tell me *why* they are down-voting this

Comment: Because it's nonsense. Hypixel is one of the biggest Minecraft servers and it's against Minecraft's terms of use to sell in-game things for real money. If they did that, it would surely be known. So you must be victim of a scam. This isn't really a proper answer that can be given to this question.

Comment: It's not a scam, thousands of people have already bought ranks on hypixel, I was just wondering if I could get one with a visa gift card. Also, ranks are usually purchased on store.hypixel.net. People have also asked this question on the Hypixel forums, but I didn't see a clear answer.

Comment: Then that's against Minecraft's usage terms. I'll talk to some people who know more about this.

Comment: I was told that these "ranks" don't actually do anything except letting you join the server faster. Is that correct? In that case, yes, it is legal: http://web.archive.org/web/20190404221116/https://mojang.com/2014/06/lets-talk-server-monetisation/ But your question made it sound like you would actually get some in-game stuff from that. Anyway, I'm not quite sure if this question is even on-topic here. You should rather ask on their forums or send them a mail.

Comment: That's basically it, all it does. I really want one because I'm almost always stuck in a queue for half an hour

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future ranks are not against EULA and they do give you access to certain things but don't give you items and don't really give you access to much more gameplay-wise

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, yes.

If not, they definitely accept Paypal. If for some reason you are not ok using your details with PayPal,  you can use the prepaid visa on a PayPal account,  then pay with that

Comment: If I used a Visa gift card, would I have to punch in the code? If so, where do I go to get to the place to put in the code.